# How to resolve Typescript error -- mapbox-gl & React hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

New to Typescript and need some clarification on how to resolve typing errors.

I'm setting the Mapbox container to mapDiv.current--it's giving me this error:

> Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLElement'.Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | HTMLElement'.ts(2322)

Though this can be fixed by doing `mapDiv.current || ''`. Is this the right way to resolve this type issue?

```
export const Map: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const mapDiv = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    let [map, setMap] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const attachMap = (setMap: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>, mapDiv: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) => {
            const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: mapDiv.current, // ERROR
                container: mapDiv.current || '', // NO ERROR
                style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
                center: [-121.91390991210938, 40.316184625814095],
                zoom: 10,
            })
            setMap(map);
        }

        !map && attachMap(setMap, mapDiv)

    }, [map])

    return (
        <div className="Map" ref={mapDiv} />
    )

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of providing a fallback string value (which might not be the most elegant solution since it is looking for a `RefObject`), you might want to do a `null`/`undefined` check before mounting mapbox in the  `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const attachMap = (setMap: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>, mapDiv: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    if (!mapDiv.current) {
      return;
    }
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapDiv.current, // ERROR
      container: mapDiv.current || '', // NO ERROR
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
      center: [-121.91390991210938, 40.316184625814095],
      zoom: 10,
    })
    setMap(map);
  }

  !map && attachMap(setMap, mapDiv)

}, [map]);
```

Comment: Huh interesting--so the typescript linter will determine if a null/undefined value has been checked and therefore not throw the error? @wentjun

Comment: Yep, that is because of the `if (!mapDiv.current)` statement that I have added on the  `attachMap` method. It does an early return if the `refObject` is falsy. Therefore, anything that passes the check will definitely be defined. That's why there is no error.

Comment: Anyways, have you tried the above code? And does it work?

Comment: Ah I see that's interesting. Yep! It works, thanks for the help, very appreciated.